# Apple TV - creating and loading dynamic library (dylib)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, dlopen, apple-tv

I would like to load a c/c++ shared object in my Apple TV project.
I create a simple library using the following tutorial:

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/CreatingDynamicLibraries.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002073-SW1)

Due to the fact i want to compile and load it into my Apple TV project i did some changes:

1. The dlopen code is in my ViewController.m on which user press a button and then dlopen is called.

   ```
   // Open the library.
   NSString * libraryname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"libRatings.A"];
   NSString * libraryfullpath = [mainBundle pathForResource:libraryname ofType:@"dylib"];

   void *lib_handle = dlopen([libraryfullpath UTF8String], RTLD_NOW);
   if (lib_handle)
   {
    printf("[%s] dlopen(\"%s\", RTLD_NOW): Successful\n", __FILE__,      "library");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("\n\n[%s] Unable to open library: %s\n",
          __FILE__, dlerror());
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   ```
2. changed the compilation command to:

   ```
   clang -dynamiclib -std=gnu99 -current_version 1.0 -compatibility_version 1.0 -fvisibility=hidden -arch arm64 -mtvos-version-min=9.2 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fembed-bitcode-marker -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS9.2.sdk Ratings.c -o libRatings.A.dylib
   ```
3. I copied my dylib into my project and verified that it is copied as a bundle resource.

When running my app, after dlopen call failed i'm getting the following error:

```
[/Users/gfsrnd/Documents/sample1/sample1/sample1/ViewController.m] Unable to open library: dlopen(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CFF7EC2A-7DF5-4270-9E99-2D5FAEBB0275/sample1 copy.app/libRatings.A.dylib, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CFF7EC2A-7DF5-4270-9E99-2D5FAEBB0275/sample1 copy.app/libRatings.A.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x1024D4000, size=0x00008000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CFF7EC2A-7DF5-4270-9E99-2D5FAEBB0275/sample1 copy.app/libRatings.A.dylib
```

Result of otool is:

```
**> otool -TV libRatings.A.dylib**
libRatings.A.dylib:
Table of contents (0 entries)
module name      symbol name
```

Result of nm is:

```
    **>nm -ag libRatings.A.dylib**

             U ___stack_chk_fail
             U ___stack_chk_guard
             U ___strncat_chk
    0000000000007d30 T _addRating
    0000000000007ecc T _clearRatings
    0000000000007db8 T _meanRating
                     U _memset
                     U _printf
    0000000000007ebc T _ratings
                     U _strdup
                     U _strlen
                     U dyld_stub_binder
```

Can anyone please advise what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You can't dynamically load code on iOS or tvOS.

Comment: Thank you. I chose to use static linking instead...

Comment: Maybe do you can to make it using this trick: http://ddeville.me/2014/04/dynamic-linking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, seems that there is no way to do dynamic loading...

I just used static linking..